# Are there any good multi-tenant Azure sample applications?

Tags: azure, multi-tenant

Are there any good multi-tenant Azure sample applications? Ideally I'd like to see some level of

- Customization of data model
- Customization of business logic
- Customization of user interface
- Automated tenant provisioning

Ideally front-end based on ASP.Net MVC3 and HTML5.

I found an old MS sample (Riviera) but it was from 2009. Also found Cloud Ninja (seems quite focused on metering), and Fabrikam Shipping Sample.

Any others I have missed? Also any other good resources/blogs on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, take a look at Cloud Ninja, both with a [.NET](http://cloudninja.codeplex.com/) implementation and a [Java](https://github.com/PersistentSys/cloudninja-for-java) implementation. You'll find several interesting areas, including:

- provisioning
- identity management
- multi-tenant database management
- tenant-level metering

I saw that you mentioned Cloud Ninja, but I wanted to clarify it's not just about metering. Tenant provisioning is key, and this is demonstrated in both .net and java versions.

Comment: Yeah I should have made it clear that Cloud Ninja look like an excellent sample. Was just hoping for some more samples that may give some guidance on customization of the tenants which (from my initial reading) didn't seem to be a focus of Cloud Ninja.