# Multi Tenant Data Architecture in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles

I want to implement multi tenant architecture for database. Plan is to have same database but have schema in it which will have same tables, sprocs, triggers, etc. repeated for each tenant. Tenant will be mapped to a schema and adding a tenant is like adding a schema.

And depending on the sub-domain, i will figure out the tenant and pull / push information to the respective database schema.

However, while looking for the way to implement the same i came across many articles and blogs and am confuse whether the word 'schema' is right in my context or should i go for Federation? And if i have to go to federation - does it mean that each tenant will be a federated member which will be mapped to a schema?

Can someone throw some more light on it?

Comment: What is driving your need to physically split the schemas for each tenant? Are you expecting the schemas to vary ever so slightly from tenant to tenant or are you expecting that each tenant would not want to be near other tenants and cause an accidental data corruption or some other reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any good multi-tenant Azure sample applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003049/are-there-any-good-multi-tenant-azure-sample-applications)

Comment: @lgorek: i want to have schemas based implementation to ensure that there is logical seperation of data and to ensure that data isolation is not at row level. So, your 2nd part of assumption - 'each tenant would not want to be near other tenants and cause an accidental data corruption or some other reason' is what is making me go schema level seperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a short series of articles for BusinessCloud9.com that may be of interest:

http://www.businesscloud9.com/user/2688

(I'd be grateful if you'd ignore the incorrect statement on the number of tables in a SQL Azure database! Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to edit the offending post to fix it)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure federations can likely do the trick for you, but it is possible to accidentally create a fan-out query where multiple databases will be queried and results unintentionally intermixed.  If you want to separate the schemas completely with no accidental mixing of data due to buggy code, you'll want multiple and distinct SQL Azure databases or schemas.  You'll want to provision them as new tenants are brought onboard.
Here's a good link on the subject: http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2011/10/05/solving-schema-separation-challenges.aspx from one of SQL Azure MVPs

Comment: @lgorek: thanks for your revert.....instead of physical database / federated members can we not have SCHEMA (like in the oracle world) where its a logical separation within the SQL Azure DB and each schema has same objects (tables, sprocs, etc) but each pointing to respective tenant? If so, any reference to it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too.  Although separate databases may let you be able to get more scale out of SQL Azure as you'd be able to place to DB's on separate servers.  Either way, check out this link: http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2011/10/05/solving-schema-separation-challenges.aspx  editing my response above

Comment: @lgorek: thanks for your help and inputs....yes, i also agree that DB separation is better. but right now, since tenants are very few (less than 5) - i feel schema level separation is fine to start with. if growth is seen, then separating them out will be any which ways possible.

Comment: Hi - Allow me to add to @igorek - you can actually do both: both database and schema separation at the same time. The key to keeping this flexible is to ensure all your tenants have a different schema name, whether or not they are on the same database. This ensures that you can move your tenants easily in the same database, or on different databases. I will soon (within days) publish version 3 of the Enzo SQL Shard on codeplex (open source) that does that with a sample app.

Comment: Thanks for the revert. However, i am facing a problem while granting rights to the user i just created under the master DB that i need to map to the schema. while i fire 'GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::schema_cust1 TO user_tenant' it gives an error Cannot find the schema 'schema_cust1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. i am sure schema_cust1 does exists since i can see that but i feel the issue is with the permission. i am logged into SQL management studio that connects to my Azure subsription using the username & password i get from the subsription. Any inputs?